Raspberry Pi 3b.Platform
I have just purchased a new Pi3b to set up as an MMDVM hotspot, the following is this genuine.
Platform:Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev. 1.2 armv7| 1GB - Stadium China - Board # a52082
OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 "bullseye" (release ver. 11.8)
1AO
Linux Kernel: 6.1.21-v7+
Uptime:
